# run MSTests from windows command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have 5 solutions all using MSTest and I would like to have a cmd file in a root folder that will run all the tests

so I would like to call the MsTests runner from the command line against

```
\Solution1\Tests\Debug\Test.dll
...
\Solution5\Tests\Debug\Test.dll
```

anybody knows how can this be done ?

Comment: For all command line options of `MSTest` check also this: [MSTest.exe Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.100))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is detailed on MSDN: [How to: Run Automated Tests from the Command Line Using MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically, you can do:

```
MSTest /testcontainer:\Solution1\Tests\Debug\Test.dll
```

Comment: I've tried doing so but it tells me: 'mstest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @OriWiesel You have to be in the right directory. The one, which contains MsTest.exe

Comment: @Nikolaus i just now understood that it is part of the visual studio's executables... i've added it to the path EV

Comment: I have the MSTest.exe in separate location and the .dll in separate location. When I try to execute through MSTest.exe (from command prompt) with the mentioned syntax. It displays the .dll file not found? What changes I need to make

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan .dll not found sounds like the file path was not correct. A frequent mistake is that you are trying to use a path environmental variable, or are trying to do a relative path, when you really need absolute path: `MSTest /testcontainer:C:\path\To\SolutionDirectory\Tests\Debug\Test.dll` . You can check if you have the correct path by copying the path to directory containing dll to File Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

If Using .Net Core:

```sh
dotnet test ./nameoftest.dll
```

In the folder where the test is located.

For command line options see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from this thread: https://gist.github.com/leniel/2438148

Just run the following command to run test cases by using `MSTest /testcontainer`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE>MSTest /testcontainer:"C:\project-name\projectTestSolutionFolder\bin\Release\ProjectTest.dll"
```